# Can rebooting a router clear any hacks done to it?

Tags: attacks, router

I manage a website for a club. I monitor the cPanel error logs to identify potential hackers that attempt to hack the website I maintain. Recently I have seen my IP address appear in the error logs and I know it is not due to my actions. I do not think that my router has been hacked so I believe my IP address may have been spoofed by a hacker.

In the unlikely event my router is hacked, is it appropriate to reboot it to the default values (and assign a new password)?

Comment: Is your network using DHCP? could be that someone just have your IP for that moment. Are you running HTTPS with a domain name associated with your server? This would rule out MitM.

Comment: You have 3 unrelated questions in a single post. Please refine to a single question. And since you already assume that hackers have spoofed your IP (and we have multiple questions on this site that answers that), I focused your question on the one you end up asking. But you have a bit of an X/Y Problem. You want to address the strangeness you see in the logs, but you've focused on specific responses, whether or not they will address the strangeness.

Comment: What you ISP will do for you is a question for your ISP, that question has been removed.

Comment: "I have seen my IP address appear in the error logs" -- what IP? Your club? Your website? Your home IP?

Comment: *"Can rebooting a router clear any hacks done to it?"* - this depends if the compromise is a persistent one or not. Both kind of compromises exist.